# About the thing in bathrooms which looks like a ladder

Tags: bathroom, furniture, bathroom-fixtures

What is the thing that is in some home bathrooms and is like a ladder (you can see it in the picture)? What is it called? What is it there for?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Usually a towel bar/rack. In that overly architectural rendering it might think it's shelves, hard to say given the limited detail in the tiny far away picture. The lack of anything ON shelves/rack seems to be common architectural photography practice, nobody lives in a house if you believe the architectural photographers.

Comment: The answers below look correct to me. This is the site that picture came from, but I could not find that exact model, so it is either retired or that is strictly an artists rendering.  https://www.abacus-bathrooms.co.uk/#!/heating/towel-warmers/stainless-steel-towel-warmers It looks like you can buy hangars that attach to the warmer Also found a much larger version https://my-bathrooms.co.uk/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That ladder like thing in a bathroom area is a combination towel rack and heater. The heater is generally used to warm and/or dry the towels but can also lend to taking the chill off the bathroom.

It has been my experience to see those mostly in Europe and I cannot actually remember ever seeing one installed in the US but I am sure they are used here.

Comment: I've put a few in high-end homes over the years. Always found them kind of decadent, personally. I can see it if you're heating your home to 58 degrees or something.

Comment: But those ones like the one in the picture is too closely installed to the wall and towels cannot be hanged on it.

Answer (score 4):

It's a towel warmer. You hang the towel like on a standard bar, and the heat elements keep the towel warm all over.

[Lots of examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=wall+mount+towel+warmer&rlz=1C1ZCEB_enUS850US850&sxsrf=ACYBGNR0FtX4B352xNN3Tv7pGHPQUpXJgg:1581438869600&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiGvrnw9snnAhUWbs0KHdflC2UQ_AUoAnoECA4QBA&biw=1842&bih=979)

Comment: But those ones like the one in the picture is too closely to the wall installed and towels cannot be hanged on it.

Comment: Bigger image: https://my-bathrooms.co.uk/

Comment: [Looks like there's plenty of gap behind the bars to me](https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-l1oby3chnp/product_images/theme_images/161005_Abacus__Set04_Shot04_1149_F4.jpg?t=1516370438).

Comment: @Learner - The correct usage for the towels is **hung**; not **hanged**.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be used for hanging clothes to dry if not wanting to use dryer, I've seen clothes rack mounted to bathroom wall in all sorts of design, it's best way to " line" dry clothes especially if you live in a apartment building with limited space, city living and eco friendly if access to outdoor line is impossible,